# How to name multi-sites for different environments (dev and staging)?

Tags: multi-sites, subsites

I have a Drupal project that is a multi-site setup. I currently have my sites named like so:

```
sites/site1.example.dev
sites/site2.example.dev
sites/site3.example.dev
```

This is fine for working locally in development, as I can point my browser to **site1.example.dev**, **site2.example.dev**, or **site3.example.dev** and it works. However, when I push this up to staging, I want to be able to access these sites at the following addresses:

```
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
site3.example.com
```

Is it possible to simply name these as "[specific_name].example" and configure it so that I don't need to rename/update depending on the environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking into aliases.

On your `sites` folder there should be a `example.sites.php`. It basically allows aliasing sites to different names.

You could create an `if` and based on some environment condition (maybe the output of `hostname`? or a file somewhere that contains `prod` vs `dev`), enable or disable the aliases.

More documentation:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/8.2.x
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7.x

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the site names for staging site in the file sites/site.php

Also update the settings.php file with the credentials of staging site.

Also need to update the site url from the host settings.